# what means "low ceilling means in "The old man at the bridge"?

Tags: meaning

The line comes from **The Old Man At The Bridge** By **Ernest Hemingway**.Here is the line:

*It was Easter Sunday and the Fascists were advancing toward the Ebro.It was a gray overcast day with a low ceiling so their planes were not up*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ceiling refers to “altitude of the base of a cloud layer” according to the OED.

**Ceiling** /ˈsiːlɪŋ  /
▸ noun

1. the upper interior surface of a room or other similar compartment:
   the books were stacked from floor to ceiling.

   - an upper limit set on prices, wages, or expenditure:
     the government imposed a wage ceiling of 3 per cent.
   - the maximum altitude that a particular aircraft can reach:
     the aircraft's quoted ceiling of 24,000 feet.
   - **the altitude of the base of a cloud layer.**

**Origin**

Middle English (denoting the action of lining the interior of a room with plaster or panelling): from *ceil* + *-ing*<sup>1</sup>. ceiling (SENSE 1) dates from the mid 16th century.

Comment: nice answer! I've adjusted the formatting for how the Stack Exchange rendering works.